# Is it possible to use remote PyCharm alongside git integration?

Tags: git, pycharm, remote-debugging

I have just set up PyCharm professional using the remote debugging functionality to connect to our cluster, but now I don't seem to be able to use the git integration.

How do I retrieve the git history of my repo, or at least let it sync with the git history on the cluster? When I type:

```
git status
```

on the cluster I see the feature branch name but locally I have no branches and no git integration.

Comment: If you want to use Git integration, you need to have a local checkout of your Git repository. The Git integration does not work over a remote connection.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. Thanks for responding!